# While loop not working as expected

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've just started learning Python a few days ago and I'm working through the Learn Python the Hard Way exercises. I've just been messing around with while loops and I can't figure out why this one continues to loop and loop and loop. It's basically just a function that populates a list and then prints the contents.

```
   from sys import argv

script = argv

print "This script is called %s." % script
print "It allows a list to be populated with a number"
print "Please enter that number:"
whilevar = raw_input()

i = 0 
numbers = []

def list_numbers(i, whilevar):
    while i < to whilevar: 
        print "At the top i is %d" % i 
        numbers.append(i)
        i = i + 1
        print "number present in list now ", numbers

list_numbers(i, whilevar) 

print "The numbers:"

for z in numbers:
    print z
```

It's probably something really basic but I'm just missing it somehow.

Thanks

Comment: This does not appear to be the real code. It's always frustrating when people fail to post the code that they are running.

Comment: `to whilevar` is wrong. You should get some syntax error there thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while i < whilevar` compares `i`, an integer, to `whilevar`, a string. (The result of `raw_input` is always a string, even if the user only enters numbers.)

In Python 2.x, integers are always less than strings. So your condition will always be true and the loop will never exit.

Others have explained how to remedy this: convert `whilevar` to an integer using `int()`. (Do not use `input()`).

I'll assume the extraneous `to` is a typo and that you know it shouldn't be there.

Comment: That did it, I'd actually come across that before but forgotten about it since. Big thanks for your help and anyone else who posted an answer. This was the exact code I was running, the to was just a typo that somehow snuck in there so apologies for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Why should he not use `input()`?

Comment: Because `input()` evaluates what the user enters as a Python expression, which is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need that `to` in there:

```
while i < to whilevar: 
          ^^
```

Also, convert `whilevar` into an integer:

```
whilevar = int(raw_input())
```

Giving it a better name won't hurt either.